# PIL fromarray for single channel image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to obtain an image shaped (1080, 1920, 1) from one shaped (1080, 1920, 3)
This is what I have been trying without success:

```
    for fr in fr_lst:
            frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(frame_root, fr))

            #SPLIT CHANNELS
            frame = (cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            r, g, b = cv2.split(frame)
            r = np.expand_dims(r, axis=2)
            print(r.shape)
            frame = Image.fromarray(r)
```

when I print the shape of r I get (1080, 1920, 1) but `Image.fromarray(r)` returns the error

```
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 1), |u1
```

I tried not expanding the dimensions, obtaining the shape of r of (1080,1920) and successfully running `Image.fromarray(r)`

I also tried to expand the dimensions of the PIL image `frame = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=(2))` which seems to return the appropriate result, but has a strange behaviour:

If I use an array of size (1080, 1920, 3) and run `size = frames[0].size` I obtain `size = 1920, 1080` which is great. But if I run `size = frames[0].size` with frames of shape (1080, 1920, 1) I obtain `size = 2073600`

My goal is to have an array of size (1920, 1080) when passing a frame of shape (1080, 1920, 1).

What am I doing wrong or not understanding?

Thank you

Comment: If you split the image into individual channels and work only with the first one, you are isolating only the red channel and discarding all green and blue information - is this what you want? Or do you want to average all channels into one? The latter would be a bgr to grayscale conversion, which can be achieved via cv2.cvtColor directly.

Comment: @stateMachine yes, I want to discard the other channels

Comment: the `COLOR_BGR2RGB` is pointless. you can collapse the color dimension of the single color plane. then maybe PIL will accept it.

Comment: why ***did*** you deliberately call `np.expand_dims()`?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I am making some changes to a larger code base and at some point downstream it needs to do some operations between two arrays. One of those arrays has the shape (1080, 1920, 1) and when I try operation between said array and my (1080, 1920), the software says they have different shapes, so I tried expanding the dimensions to match the shapes

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make sense. If you have a BGR frame with shape (1920,1080,3) and you want a single channel image, it will have shape (1920,1080).

You can either take one channel:

```
singleChannel = im[..., 0]   # take Blue channel
singleChannel = im[..., 1]   # take Green channel
singleChannel = im[..., 2]   # take Red channel
```

Or you can convert to greyscale and take that:

```
singleChannel = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: OP deliberately uses `np.expand_dims`. that causes the issue. I don't know why PIL would reject that. It's functionally equivalent, or it *should* be, regardless of what PIL thinks.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz that's what I thought as well. I understand it doesn't make sense, that's why I asked here